# Java Array If Empty multiple classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, if-statement, for-loop

I am kind of stuck on this one.

```
//DataBase class    

public int getStorageSize() 
{ 
    myStorageSize=5;
    return myStorageSize;
}
```

`BookIds[]` is empty by default.

```
public boolean isRowEmpty(int libPos)
{
    if(bookIds[libPos] == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here comes the code from main class

```
for(int i = 0; i < myDB.getStorageSize(); ++i) 
    if(myDB.isRowEmpty(i) == true)
    {
        id = i;
        break;
    }
```

I fixed it. No need to post anymore. I added this

```
public int getBookId(int libPos)
{
    return bookIds[libPos]; 
}
```

and replaced
my cycle.

```
for(int i = 1; i < myDB.getStorageSize(); i++)                                       
    if(myDB.isRowEmpty(myDB.getBookId(i)) == true)
    {
        id=i;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: please provide a small runnable example of your problem, it´s hard to follow what is actually happening here.

Comment: break; statement is breaking the loop when id=0 and no further increment is happening.

Comment: @rakeb.mazharul doesn't matter, syntax is okay.

Comment: Thanks Shivam. That's kinda was the issue.

Comment: Instead of `if(bookIds[libPos] == 0) { return true; } else { return false; }`, just do `return bookIds[libPos] == 0;`

Comment: And instead of `if(myDB.isRowEmpty(i)==true)`, just do `if(myDB.isRowEmpty(i))`

Answer (score 0):

In java by default array values are initialized with '0', so in the for loop the if condition passes for first iteration with index (i=0), that is why id value becoming 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined id somewhere ie. `id=1` and then check

```
if(id == 1) {
    id = i;
    break;
}
```

into your for loop.

Comment: i already fixed it. i kinda did the same thing. Thank you anyway :)